# What's this design style on Google's I/O webpage called?

Tags: website-design, style-identification

The following image was found on [Google's I/O](https://io.google/2022/#:%7E:text=various%20product%20zones-,.,-Launch) webpage. What's this design-style that Google seems to have adopted called?

If I were to make an educated guess, I would call this flat-art, but it seems to be slightly different compared to the flat-art designs I have seen so far.

[image]

Comment: Not every style has a name.

Comment: Make up one that's descriptive. For this I'd say something like "flat geometric with thick outlines"

Comment: Searching for "shooting target" gives at least the most of the image. Insert only the colored objects. If you reveal what you actually want to find by using the style name (which you probably do not get) someone may be able to answer.